# Unable to locate element: [id="password"]

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the 'By' class in the Selenium Python library to locate an element on a webpage by its name attribute. However, when I try to use the 'By.Name' attribute, I get an error saying "type object 'By' has no attribute 'Name'.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/signin")

 #find element by id and send keys
usernames = driver.find_element(By.ID,"identifierId")
usernames.send_keys('masudalnahid0')

Button = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierNext')
Button.click()

try:
    ps = driver.find_element(By.Name,'password')
    time.sleep(3)
    ps.send_keys('GoodMorning')
    time.sleep(3)
except:
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'password').send_keys("GoodMorning")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element(By.ID,'submit').click()
    time.sleep(6)
```

I have also tried using the 'name' attribute with the same result. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and how to properly use the 'By' class to locate an element by its name attribute?

I expected the code to locate out id=password and send.keys('password')

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), it should be `By.NAME` (capitalized):

> ```
> find_element(By.ID, "id")
> find_element(By.NAME, "name")
> find_element(By.XPATH, "xpath")
> find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "link text")
> find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "partial link text")
> find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "tag name")
> find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "class name")
> find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "css selector")
> ```

Instead of:

```
ps = driver.find_element(By.Name,'password')
```

Use:

```
 ps = driver.find_element(By.NAME,'password')
```